# koa2-swagger-ui Authentication

Tags: swagger, koa

I'm using JWT for a Koa based application, and I'm using koa2-swagger-ui for some api documentation. Some routes are protected, and the user must have a JWT to access them. Has anyone had any luck figuring out how to format the swagger yaml file to support this? I've looked at a lot of documentation but nothing seems to work!